# Do I need the alternate installer to install on a box with existing raid 0?

Tags: installation, raid

I have an existing machine with three drives, two of which are joined in a raid 0; on my old distro, this was mounted at `/home`

When I went to install Oneiric, it recognized each drive separately; the main drive is no problem, but there was no way to note that that the other two drives were raided together.

From what I've read, the Alternate install is required for an install including RAIDed drives.  Do I *need* this, even though it's not going to house the root filesystem?  Is it a particular hassle to do this after install on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the alternate install is not needed.  After booting the desktop install, you simply have to do the following as root:

```
apt-get install mdadm
mdadm --assemble --scan
```

Then, running `blkid` will give the `UUID` of the drive; this can be used to add an entry for the drive to `/etc/fstab`.

It's that simple!